# Exclude some keywords or prevent users to search some keywords

Tags: 2013, search-results, enterprise-search

How to exclude or prevent users from search below keywords
all, docs, test etc, if users search using these keywords SharePoint search must not display any results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201816/can-you-exclude-words-from-search

Answer (score 1):

What's the reason for this? If it is to prevent the users from getting their hands on files they shouldn't then it's a no go. There's literally several other way to surface the files other than search.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the answer by Morten K in that there are always ways to get around a keyword exclusion, it does not accurately respond to the question.

You can find a way to run query rules that cause exclusion of certain keywords here: [Exclude Keywords from Search](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201816/can-you-exclude-words-from-search)

Comment: True - in hindsight it should have been a comment. Out of curiosity can you implement at global query rule or would it need to be set on every single search form in the farm?

Comment: Honestly, I have never tried either as I do not see the point in excluding this way. I would rather exclude based on permissions. However, I would believe that you should be able to exclude in this manner globally as long as someone is not using custom search boxes that are using their own rules.